# Why can't I install Pandas on 16.04?

Tags: command-line, python3, python-2.7

What my terminal looks like at the moment...

[image: terminal appearance]

I have no idea what the terminal message means because I'm still new to Ubuntu but I searched for it and have already tried aliasing Python for Python3...

Comment: Can you be more specific? How did you alias Python for Python 3?

Comment: Please don't post photos of text. Copy-paste the text, then use the formatting tools to make the formatting work.

Comment: Are you trying to install Pandas via Pip for Python 2 (`pip`) or Python 3 (`pip3`)? In any case please [don't make `python` refer to Python 3](/q/777085/175814)!

Answer (score 4):

I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

But also needed others like this:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade numexpr
```

Whatever you do, do not uninstall or modify default python, python2 or python3. System uses python and changes will totally break Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This might be as simple as:
`sudo pip install pandas`

Or depending on how pip is configured:
`python -m pip install --user pandas`